# How to call function in recursive manner in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, php-5.3

I am trying to create a Dynamic header for which i am using recursive logic inside a class function.

I'm using this on the view side.

```
    <nav class="primary-menu uppercase">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <?php
                include("modules/listMenu.php");
                $list->menu(0);
        ?>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Below is the code m using in the class.

```
class listMenu Extends Connection
    {
        public function menu($parent_id)
            {
                $query = ' SELECT id, name, slug FROM categories WHERE status = 1 AND parent_id = "'.$parent_id.'" ';
                $connection = $this->establish_connection();
                $data = $connection->query($query);
                $connection->close();
                if($data->num_rows > 0)
                    {
                        while($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                                // print_r($row);
                                // exit();
                                $menu .="<li><a href='".$row['slug']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";
                                $menu .= "<ul>".$this->menu($row['id'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively
                                $menu .= "</li>";
                            }

                        return $menu;
                    }
            }
    }

$list = new listMenu();
```

i'm using `$this->menu($row['id'])` recursively to achieve recusion login, but  getting an error saying that `NOTICE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: MENU`

What's the reason of this error. What am i missing?

Comment: `$menu` is never defined. `$menu .= 'something'` is the equivalent of `$menu = $menu . 'something'` so you need to initialize your variable first (with an empty string here, I suppose).

Comment: i used in earlier php version it was ok if i don't use this, seems like from php 7 it's been strict

Comment: as a sidenote, PHP 5.3 end of life was reached in August 2014, please consider updating to a still-supported version :) http://php.net/eol.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think will help

```
class listMenu Extends Connection
{
    public function menu($parent_id)
        {
            $query = ' SELECT id, name, slug FROM categories WHERE status = 1 AND parent_id = "'.$parent_id.'" ';
            $connection = $this->establish_connection();
            $data = $connection->query($query);
            $connection->close();
            if($data->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    $menu = '';
                    while($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            $menu .="<li><a href='".$row['slug']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";
                            $menu .= "<ul>".$this->menu($row['id'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively
                            $menu .= "</li>";
                        }

                    return $menu;
                }
        }
}
```

$list = new listMenu();

Comment: please add `$menu` out of while loop, at every loop it is being reset. Please do the change so that i can mark your answer